# Stacked bar chart with dual axis in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Please consider the example below:

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                               pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                               pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03'),
                               pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03')],
                      'group': ['a','b','a','b'],
                      'value': [1,3,3,5]})

myline = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02'),
                                 pd.to_datetime('2021-01-03')],
                       'value':[39,46]})

mydata
Out[222]: 
        time group  value
0 2021-01-02  a     1    
1 2021-01-02  b     3    
2 2021-01-03  a     3    
3 2021-01-03  b     5
```

I am trying to create a dual axis chart with the line in `myline` on one axis and the stacked bar charts from `mydata` on another.

My code below almost achieves that, but there are few issues:

1. The bars are not stacked !
2. Because my data has many different categories, I need to use a `colorscale` with many different colors like `dark24` (https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/). How can I specify that for the fill color of the bars?

Any suggestion greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=myline['time'], 
               y=myline["value"], 
               name="Column1", 
               mode="lines"),
    secondary_y=True
)

layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack')

for t in mydata['group'].unique():
    dfp = mydata.loc[mydata['group']==t]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfp['time'], 
                          y = dfp['value'], 
                          name=t,
                          text = t),
                  secondary_y=False)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Letter")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Column2", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Column1", secondary_y=True)
fig.update(layout_showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacked graph is set, but it was not enabled, so I changed the bar graph mode to stacked along with hiding the legend. Also, I couldn't find a colormap setting in graph_objects, so I updated the default colormap with the desired colormap. I checked the test data with three objects, and they are updated with the new color map. However, I did not go as far as to check the 24 colors, so you will have to check it yourself.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Dark24

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=myline['time'], 
               y=myline["value"], 
               name="Column1", 
               mode="lines"),
    secondary_y=True
)

#layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack')

for t in mydata['group'].unique():
    dfp = mydata.loc[mydata['group']==t]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfp['time'], 
                          y = dfp['value'], 
                          name=t,
                          text = t),
                  secondary_y=False)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Letter")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Column2", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Column1", secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, barmode='stack')

fig.layout.colorway = colors
fig.show()
```

[image]